# Cannot receive readyRead signal of QTcpSocket?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, qtnetwork

You send data across network with QTcpSocket, connect the readyRead signal with your data handler. But readyRead signal maybe not triggered.

You could see the data arrived with Wireshark, but QTcpSocket does not trigger the readyRead signal.

Comment: normally, it should trigger readyRead signal. check ur receiver side.

Comment: I have the same or similar issue. Win7 x64, Qt 5.1. Wireshark shows that messages arrive, but only one in every 4-10 messages will trigger readyRead(). It has got me stumped.

Answer (score -1):

This could happen if your thread created the socket is in a modal dialog which enters its own event loop preventing readyRead signal from triggering.

I come up with 2 solutions:
1) use non-modal dialog, provide the dialog result with signal.
2) create the socket within another thread.

Comment: A normal modal dialog does not block event handling, Qt takes care of that.